# Extract a number of characters before a substring pattern with regex

Tags: r, regex, string, extract

I have this string

```
"1 36,8 stc smear"
```

This means that the first smear was made from inpatient that had temperature 36,8

And I would like to get only the temperature

```
36,8
```

I used this

```
str_extract("1 36,8 stc smear", "(\\d)+(?= stc)")
```

But output was

```
8
```

Is it possible to get all the digits with "," to get output `36,8`

Comment: I think you are looking for `\\d+(?:,\\d+)?(?= stc)`

Comment: @JvdV I don't think that a patient with a negative temperature reading is going to be getting seen by a doctor :0

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thank you - It works. Could you, please, provide me an explanation of your regex?

Comment: @onhalu It matches 1 or more digits `\\d+` and then optionally matches a comma and again 1 or more digits using `(?:,\\d+)?` Note that you don't need the capture group around the number if you want a match only.